# Laptop background noise

Tags: noise, ramdisk

In my acer laptop with i5-7200 8GB RAM I hear a constant background noise which an HP AMD Quad-Core A8-7410 doens't have, though I hear the CPU working when performing more taks in this last one that I don't hear in the first one. Should this be related with the hardware and thus be normal or with the quality of construction of the laptops? I mean if I had an HP with exactly the same CPU as the Acer, I would also hear the same or might not, due to different brand and type of construction?

Comment: Can you be more specific about the nature of the noise?  There are a few different components that can produce noise, so the answer kind of depends on which noise you're talking about.

Answer (score 0):

I am not an expert by far but I guess the noice you describe is probably related to the fan speed of the cooling system. As far as I know the fans are often programmed to run at certain speeds depending on the CPU temperature. Depending on your operating system these temperatures can be traced via different ways. A simple google search should help you get a long way with that.

My approach to trouble-shoot your problem would be:

1. See if your CPU runs at a (too) high temperature. If so:

   - check if any system processes are using a lot of cpu. (Usually a "ps aux" command via the command line should help you see all running processes and their CPU usage, on windows the ctrl+alt+del screen should show an option to list these processes as well I believe.)
   - **If it is**: indeed a system process that is running wild, you can either force quit the process or look for another more specific cure.
   - **If it is not**: This means the CPU-temp is high without any processes using its resources I would advise you to post the specifics of your findings in a new post and ask for help as it might be your CPU is broken.
2. If your CPU-temp is fine, the problem is most likely in the fan speed of your cooling system.

   - A google search should help you uncover how to read the fan speed on your operation system and find out what the 'normal' values are supposed to be for your laptop's cooling system. If your fan speed is indeed too high it is often possible to tone it down via the command line. See if you can find out how or post a more specific question on that. Also, see if others might help you uncover why your fan speed was too high in the first place.
   - If your fan speed and CPU temp are both normal it might be that one laptop is simply more loud then the other due to factory defaults. At least, as far as I am aware of.

As said, I am not an expert but hopefully this helps.

Comment: I appreciate your answer but I don't think the noise is from the fan, because it is the permament noise of the pc working, not from the fan that only acts once in a while (I never heard it), so I guess it is from the HDD itself. Maybe the HP has better isolating acustic materials than acer.

Comment: Well, if it's from the HDD you could check the RPM of the disk. If it is higher then then that of the other laptop, that would explain a bit more noise. Off course, different isolation might also be a cause, but I cannot tell from you question just how bad the noise really is? If an HDD is producing irritatingly loud noises I would still advise step 1 from my answer, but then relating it to HDD use.